# How to use react Router to handle the URL /?search=keyword?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router-dom 6.4.2.

#### The expected result:

When the user browses the link http://mysite/?search=123,
my website returns the search result of `123`,

Here is my App.js:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path='/?search=:keyword' element={<SearchEng />} />
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

#### The actual result:

Unfortunately, when a user browses the link http://mysite/?search=123,
it always returns the `Home` component.

Would you help to fix the problem?

Comment: @AndyRay The solution does not work.

Answer (score 1):

it should be something like this:

**in App.js**

```js
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path='/search' element={<SearchEng />} />
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

**in SearchEng.js**

add this line in your component. [document about useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params)

```js
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const params = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams]);
  console.log(params);
}, [])
```

when you go to `http://mysite/search?search=123`, you should get `{ search: "123" }` in console.

Comment: Because of historical issues, the solution not 100% fit my case. However, I will try your implementation in my environment.

Comment: @TheKNVB i found [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-usesearchparams-0neu9?file=/src/App.js) that might help.